# Does stringstream ignoring whitespaces?

Tags: c++, stream, stringstream

I was reading about stringstream and found this example.

```
stringstream ss;
int foo;
int bar = 0;

ss << 100 << ' ' << 200;
ss >> foo;
ss >> bar;

cout << "foo: " << foo << '\n'; // 100
cout << "bar: " << bar << '\n'; // 200
```

Why the value of variable 'bar' is 200? Shouldn't a 'bar' read a space from stream and get an ASCII code for space (32), or some other values? Does stringstream ignoring whitespaces? Then why if we add a line  here:

```
ss >> foo;
ss.ignore(1);
ss >> bar;
```

the bar's value still 200 isntead of 0?

Comment: If you use `>>` with `cin` does it ignore whitespaces? Why do you think a `stringstream` should be different? Surely it would make more sense if it was the same?

Comment: @john -- "Surely it would make sense if it was the same" is not the same as "it is the same".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does stringstream ignoring whitespaces?

Technically the `operator>>()` function ignores leading whitespace. Doing `ss.ignore(1)` is a way to do it manually, but it's unnecessary.

On the other hand, the function `std::getline()` does not skip whitespace. So if there is leading whitespace you will have to remove it manually.